# Why is Context "becoming" null on Application class?

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-context

Problem using Application

I'm rewriting an app (first 'version' had little-to-nothing in terms of analysis and it ended up piling a bunch of problems I wanted to get rid of) and I'm bumping my head against a problem that never showed up in the first version.

Thing is: I have a Class for geographical data. It just supplies String arrays that I can tuck into spinners adapters. Since I used a values xml file, the class needs access to Context to get the proper resources.

Since I use this geographical data in several points of the app, I thought I could create a Class to extend Application and, in onCreate, instantiate the Geography Class, I thought it would be more efficient to load it just once and use it as many times as I wanted. This worked on my first version:

This is MyApplication class

```
private static Context context;
public void onCreate(){
    super.onCreate();
    MyApplication.context = getApplicationContext();
    geografiaEspana = GeographyClass.getInstance(context);

}
public static GeographyClass getGeografiaEspana() {
        if(ctx==null){
            Log.w("TAPABOOK", "Tapabook.context nulo");
        }
        if (geografiaEspana==null){
            Log.w("TAPABOOK", "Tapabook.geografiaEspana nula, instanciando");

            geografiaEspana = GeographyClass.getInstance(ctx);
        }
        Log.i("TAPABOOK", "Tapabook.geografiaEspana instanciada");
        return geografiaEspana;
    }
```

And this is my GeographyClass

```
private static GeographyClass instance = null;
public static GeographySpain getInstance(Context context){
    if(instance== null){
        instance = new GeographySpain(context);
    }
    return instance;
}


public GeographySpain(Context context){
    Resources res = context.getResources();
    // load resources data
    }
```

This worked, as I said, ok in my first version. However, in my new version I'm getting a NullPointerException on this line "Resources res = context.getResources();" I've checked and it turns out that the context I'm supplying it's null... And I don't get to understand why or what I'm doing wrong

Comment: try context = getApplicationContext(); or else pass an instance of the activity class itself to the GeographyClass.

Comment: instead of `MyApplication.context = getApplicationContext();` put something like this: `MyApplication.context = this;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I solved it (I'd swear I already commented on this, but since it's gone...).
Thing is, I'm not used to use Application classes and I had forgotten to declare MyApplication in the Manifest file. Noob mistake. As soon as I declared it, the app ran OK